# Fast technique for normalizing a matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, normalization, performance

I want to normalise each column of a matrix in Matlab. I have tried two implementations:

Option A:

```
mx=max(x);
mn=min(x);
mmd=mx-mn;
for i=1:size(x,1)
    xn(i,:)=((x(i,:)-mn+(mmd==0))./(mmd+(mmd==0)*2))*2-1; 
end
```

Option B:

```
mn=mean(x);
sdx=std(x);
for i=1:size(x,1)
    xn(i,:)=(x(i,:)-mn)./(sdx+(sdx==0));
end
```

However, these options take too much time for my data, e.g. 3-4 seconds on a 5000x53 matrix. Thus, is there any better solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember, in MATLAB, vectorizing = speed.

If `A` is an M x N matrix,

```
A = rand(m,n);
minA = repmat(min(A), [size(A, 1), 1]);
normA = max(A) - min(A);               % this is a vector
normA = repmat(normA, [length(normA) 1]);  % this makes it a matrix
                                       % of the same size as A
normalizedA = (A - minA)./normA;  % your normalized matrix
```

Answer (score 15):

Use [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) instead of the loop. This may be a bit faster; however, it may also use more memory (which may be an issue in your case; if you're paging, everything'll be really slow).

To normalize with mean and std, you'd write

```
mn = mean(x);
sd = std(x);
sd(sd==0) = 1;

xn = bsxfun(@minus,x,mn);
xn = bsxfun(@rdivide,xn,sd);
```

Comment: Why do you use `sd(sd==0) = 1;` instead of `sd(sd==0) = eps;` ?

Comment: @tashuhka: because I divide by the value of `sd` later. If I divide by 1, the result is unchanged; if I divide by `eps`, the result is multiplied by a large number.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I guess this is a matter of preference. The operation `0/eps` returns always zero, so there is not problem with the division. However, if I want to keep the `sd` matrix for further analysis, the `eps` value gives a better representation of the actual variability than zero.

Answer (score 4):

Let `X` be a `m x n` matrix and you want to normalize column wise.

The following matlab code does it

```
XMean = repmat(mean(X),m,1);
XStd = repmat(std(X),m,1);
X_norm = (X - XMean)./(XStd);
```

The element wise ./ operator is explained here: http://www.mathworks.in/help/matlab/ref/arithmeticoperators.html

**Note:** As op mentioned, this is simply a faster solution and performs the same task as looping through the matrix. The underlying implementation of this inbuilt function makes it work faster

Comment: This normalizes the matrix so that each column has zero-mean, unit variance.  The original question simply wants to normalize each column to `[0,1]`.  YMMV.

Answer (score 3):

Note: I am not providing a freshly new answer, but I am comparing the proposed answers.

Option A: Using `bsxfun()`

```
function xn = normalizeBsxfun(x)

    mn = mean(x);
    sd = std(x);
    sd(sd==0) = eps;

    xn = bsxfun(@minus,x,mn);
    xn = bsxfun(@rdivide,xn,sd);

end
```

Option B: Using a for-loop

```
function xn = normalizeLoop(x)

    xn = zeros(size(x));

    for ii=1:size(x,2)
        xaux = x(:,ii);
        xn(:,ii) = (xaux - mean(xaux))./mean(xaux);
    end

end
```

We compare both implementations for different matrix sizes:

```
expList = 2:0.5:5;
for ii=1:numel(expList)
    expNum = round(10^expList(ii));
    x = rand(expNum,expNum); 
    tic;
    xn = normalizeBsxfun(x);
    ts(ii) = toc; 
    tic;
    xn = normalizeLoop(x);
    tl(ii) = toc; 
end

figure;
hold on;
plot(round(10.^expList),ts,'b');
plot(round(10.^expList),tl,'r');
legend('bsxfun','loop');
set(gca,'YScale','log')
```

The results show that for small matrices, the `bsxfun` is faster. But, the difference is neglect able for higher dimensions, as it was also found in other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22383813/efficient-operations-of-big-non-sparse-matrices-in-matlab).

[image]

The x-axis is the squared root number of matrix elements, while the y-axis is the computation time in seconds.

Answer (score 3):

**Note:** This code works in Octave and MATLAB versions R2016b or higher.

```
function X_norm = normalizeMatrix(X)      
      mu = mean(X); %mean    
      sigma = std(X); %standard deviation   
      X_norm = (X - mu)./sigma;    
end
```

Comment: This does not work in matlab, while it does work in octave.

Comment: This doesn't work with legacy versions of MATLAB (pre-2016b).  As of R2016b, automatic broadcasting is enabled so this would work with those versions of MATLAB.

Comment: Also note that this code performs normalization with zero-mean, unit variance.  This does not necessarily accomplish what the OP wants which is simply normalizing each column to the range of `[0,1]`.

Answer (score 1):

How about using

```
normc(X)
```

that would normalize the matrix X columnwise. You need to include the Neural Network Toolbox in your install though.

Comment: This doesn't add anything meaningful to the current list of answers... not to mention that it relies on a toolbox when all the other methods don't.

Answer (score -3):

How about this?

A = [7, 2, 6; 3, 8, 4]; % a 2x3 matrix

Asum = sum(A); % sum the columns

Anorm = A./Asum(ones(size(A, 1), 1), :); % normalise the columns

Comment: The duplication of the elements with `Asum(ones(...))` is very hazardous for larger sized matrices.  You will see huge performance bottlenecks if the size of the matrix is large.