# element wise operation - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix in MATLAB, lets say:

```
a = [
  89  79  96  
  72  51  74  
  94  88  87  
  69  47  78
]
```

I want to subtract from each element the average of its column and divide by the column's standard deviation. How can I do it in a way which could be implemented to any other matrix without using loops.

thanks

Comment: similar question: [Fast technique for normalizing a matrix in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521593/fast-technique-for-normalizing-a-matrix-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `repmat` to make your average/std vector the same size as your original matrix, then use direct computation like so:

```
[rows, cols] = size(a); %#to get the number of rows

avgc= repmat(avg(a),[rows 1]); %# average by column, vertically replicated by number of rows
stdc= repmat(std(a),[rows 1]); %# std by column, vertically replicated by number of rows
%# Here, a, avgc and stdc are the same size
result= (a - avgc) ./ stdc;
```

Edit:

Judging from a [mathworks blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/),[`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.fr/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html) solution is faster and consumes less memory (see acai answer). For moderate size matrices, I personally prefer repmat that makes code easier to read and debug (for me).

Comment: I would disagree that use of bsxfun is harder to read or debug! In fact, either usage is best preceded by a comment, describing what you are doing. Comments take no time to execute. They cost little to write, compared to the time they save in debugging, and when you need to change your code next year, or when you need to modify the code inherited from the fellow who was run over by the crosstown bus last week.

Comment: @woodchips hence the 'I _personally_ prefer'. This is subjective, I edited my answer to stress this a little more.

Comment: My point is, in any case, use comments to make the code readable, in which case there is no valid reason (beyond pure inertia) to use the inefficient older style. Learning to use the better forms as a habit will improve your code.

Comment: With `repmat`, it is clear which dimension is the singleton that is being "broadcasted"(using numpy term). I can only think of this one way that is more readable than bsxfun, but as @woodchips said, you can always use comment.

Comment: but for ppl new to matlab, `repmat` forces you to think about which dimensions you want to expand, so it is a better exercise comparing to bsxfun

Comment: `repmat` uses more memory, is slow, and doesn't parallelise or generalise well. `bsxfun` is almost certainly faster, more robust and more useful in the long term. Personally, I also find it a clearer expression of intent as well as being more compact.

Answer (score 5):

If your version supports `bsxfun` (which is probably the case unless you have very old matlab version), you should use it, it's much faster than `repmat`, and consumes much less memory. 
You can just do: `result = bsxfun(@rdivide,bsxfun(@minus,a,mean(a)),std(a))`

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the [ZSCORE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/zscore.html) function from the Statistics Toolbox:

```
result = zscore(a)
```

In fact, it calls BSXFUN underneath, but it is careful not to divide by a zero standard deviation (you can look at the source code yourself: `edit zscore`)