# Efficient operations of big non-sparse matrices in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, bigdata, bsxfun

I need to operate in big 3-dim non-sparse matrices in Matlab. Using pure vectorization gives a high computation time. So, I have tried to split the operations into 10 blocks and then parse the results.
I got surprised when I saw the the pure vectorization does not scale very well with the data size as presented in the following figure.

[image]

I include an example of the two approaches.

```
% Parameters:
M = 1e6;  N = 50;  L = 4;  K = 10;

% Method 1: Pure vectorization
mat1 = randi(L,[M,N,L]);
mat2 = repmat(permute(1:L,[3 1 2]),M,N);
result1 = nnz(mat1>mat2)./(M+N+L);

% Method 2: Split computations
result2 = 0;
for ii=1:K
    mat1 = randi(L,[M/K,N,L]);
    mat2 = repmat(permute(1:L,[3 1 2]),M/K,N);
    result2 = result2 + nnz(mat1>mat2);
end
result2 = result2/(M+N+L);
```

Hence, I wonder if there is any other approach that makes big matrix operations in Matlab more efficient. I know it is a quite broad question, but I will take the risk :)

---

Edit:

Using the implementation of @Shai

```
% Method 3
mat3 = randi(L,[M,N,L]);
result3 = nnz(bsxfun( @gt, mat3, permute( 1:L, [3 1 2] ) ))./(M+N+L);
```

The times are:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why `repmat` and not `bsxfun`?

```
result = nnz(bsxfun( @gt, mat1, permute( 1:L, [3 1 2] ) ))./(M+N+L);
```

It seems like you are using up your RAM and the OS starts to allocate room in swap for the very large matrics. Memory swapping is always a very time consuming operation and it gets worse as the amount of memory you require increases.
I believe you are witnessing [thrashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Thank you. It was exactly was I was looking for to deal with big matrices.

Comment: In the documentation of `bsxfun`, I found the explanation of the singleton expansion: "*Whenever a dimension of A or B is singleton (equal to one), bsxfun virtually replicates the array along that dimension to match the other array*". I actually didn't know about this useful feature.

Comment: @tashuhka `bsxfun` is very useful. see its tag wiki for more info