# scale() R function equivalent in Octave/Matlab

Tags: r, matlab, octave

Avoiding loops, is there a way to center a matrix of data around the mean of the columns (or rows), scaling each entry by the standard deviation (also column-wise or row-wise)?

In R this is easy: `scale(data, center = T, scale = T))`.

But I don't know how to achieve the same basic pre-processing in Ocatave or Matlab.

Comment: Did you look at this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4521593/fast-technique-for-normalizing-a-matrix-in-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a single function that does this but you can use the `dim` parameter for `std` and `mean` to accomplish this. We can also use `bsxfun` to wrap it all into one line.

```
A = rand(5, 4);

% Column-wise
bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus, A, mean(A, 1)), std(A, [], 1))

% Row-wise  
bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus, A, mean(A, 2)), std(A, [], 2))
```

**Explanation**

Using the `dim` parameter to `mean` we can compute the mean value for each column of `A`.

```
M = mean(A, 1)
```

Then we can use `bsxfun` to subtract the mean from each value in each column (`@minus`). We need to use `bsxfun` because `M` is `1 x nCols` and `A` is `nRows x nCols`. `bsxfun` will automatically broadcast the operation for us.

```
B = bsxfun(@minus, A, M);
```

Then we want to compute the standard deviation of each column, again using the `dim` parameter (third input).

```
S = std(A, [], 1)
```

And divide each column by this standard deviation

```
bsxfun(@rdivide, B, S);
```

So bringing this all together we get

```
bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus, A, mean(A, 1)), std(A, [], 1))
```

To perform the row-wise operation, all we need to do is switch the `dim` parameter from 1 (columns) to 2 (rows).

Comment: Completely new at Ocatve/Matlab... Would you be so kind as to tell me what `@` does?

Comment: @AntoniParellada Adding a description now.

Comment: @AntoniParellada Do you want it divided or multiplied by the standard deviation?

Comment: I was going to ask now... It should be divided if we are going to perform PCA or gradient descent; so do you just type `@divide`? And also, what is the meaning or need of the `[]` part in `std(A,[],1)`?

Comment: @AntoniParellada I just updated it with division. You want to use [`rdivide`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rdivide.html). Also the `[]` input is because the second input is the weight and the `[]` ensures that the default value is used http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/std.html#inputarg_w

Comment: @AntoniParellada Look at the link I posted in my response.

Comment: @AntoniParellada MATLAB is column-major so the first dimension is down the columns and the second dimension is across the rows.

Answer (score 4):

In Octave, you have two functions for this center() and zscore(). center just subtracts the mean, whereas zscore also divides by sd (an operation sometimes known as known as standarization)

> center (x)
>
> Center data by subtracting its mean.
>
> If x is a vector, subtract its mean. If x is a matrix, do the above for each
>   column. If the optional argument dim is given, operate along this
>   dimension.

and

> zscore (x, opt, dim) Computes the Z score of x
>
> if x is a vector, subtract its mean and divide by its standard deviation.
>   If the standard deviation is zero, divide by 1 instead.
>
> The optional parameter opt determines the normalization to use when
>   computing the standard deviation and has the same definition as the
>   corresponding parameter for std.
>
> If x is a matrix, calculate along the first non-singleton dimension.
>   If the third optional argument dim is given, operate along this
>   dimension.