# Scale only certain columns R

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I scale(x) only certain columns of a dataframe? I have a dataframe with 7 columns and I want to scale only column 3 and 6. The rest should stay as it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scale() R function equivalent in Octave/Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37378168/scale-r-function-equivalent-in-octave-matlab)

Comment: Duplicate of: [R Apply() function on specific dataframe columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503177/r-apply-function-on-specific-dataframe-columns)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We can do this with `lapply`.  Subset the columns of interest, loop through them with `lapply`, assign the output back to the subset of data.  Here, we are using `c` because the outpuf of `scale` is a `matrix` with a single column. Using `c` or `as.vector`, it gets converted to `vector`

```
df[c(3,6)] <- lapply(df[c(3, 6), function(x) c(scale(x)))
```

---

Or another option is `mutate_at` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate_at(c(3,6), funs(c(scale(.))))
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast and easy answer!

Comment: Late answer, but you could also simply use `df[c(3, 6)] <- scale(df[c(3, 6)])`

Comment: df %>%  mutate_at(c(3,6), scale)